# ¿Cómo evito que un div se posicione encima de otro?

Tags: html, css, datatables, bootstrap-4

Tengo esto hecho en CSS y todavía no he podido dar con que el `rightside` cuando hago más pequeña la ventana del navegador, no se sobreponga al `leftside` me gustaría que quedara simplemente debajo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.4/datatables.min.css"/>

        <title></title>
        
        <style type="text/css">

            .leftside, .rightside{
                height: 80vh;
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            @media only screen and (max-width:800px){
                .leftside, .rightside{
                    height: 100vh;
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
            
            .leftside{
                background: #e6fffe;
                box-sizing: content-box;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: block;
            }
            
            .rightside{
                background: #f3e3ff;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: right;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: block;
            }
            
            #formulario{
                float: none;
                margin: auto;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                padding-top: 25px;
            }
        </style>
        
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
                <div class="leftside">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        
                        <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                    <th>Editar</th>
                                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>Location</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-info">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
                <div class="rightside">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" id="formulario">
                        <br>
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Enter your name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Location:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Enter your location">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="update">Update</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

En la siguiente captura se muestra cómo se va posicionando encima del contenido azul cuando la ventana del navegador se hace más pequeño lo cual no debe ocurrir y debería simplemente quedarse en su posición debajo del contenido azul.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se, a mi me parece que ya lo hace bien... míralo tu mismo aquí a ver si puedes explicármelo mejor:   https://jsfiddle.net/7vk51w04/

Comment: Lo que sucede y no quiero que siga sucediendo es que al hacer lo más pequeña la ventana del navegador, el `rightside` se mueva sobre el `leftside` porque usualmente el `rightside` se sobrepone y tapa todo el contenido del `leftside`, prefiero que se quede debajo y no se mueva cuando la ventana sea más pequeña incluso más de lo que dice en `@media`

Comment: pues a mi me parece que funciona bien

Comment: Ya, eso lo entenderia si supiera reproducirlo, pero tal como se muestra en el enlace que te he pasado antes, si lo ejecutas pulsando RUN, y modificas el tamaño de la salida HTML seleccionando los bordes de esa salida, el rightside se va debajo sin tapar el leftside. Por eso digo que ya parece que funciona bien.

Comment: En el propio snippet que tu has puesto en la pregunta tampoco lo veo superpuesto, simplemente se va debajo tambien.

Comment: Añadí una imagen para mostrar cuando es que se sobrepone, es cuando se hace más pequeña la ventana del navegador y lo que requiero es que se quede debajo sin moverse.

Comment: Eso pasa xq has dado un vh de 80vh. O le pones height auto o Saca el overflow hidden. Ponle visible o scroll

Comment: Me sirvió @HernánGarcia, gracias